# Compute $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{(\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}} ) \cdot \ln(x-1)}$

Tags: limits

I found a way to solve the problem on emathhelp.net, they simplify the expression as follows:

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{(\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}} ) \cdot \ln(x-1)} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{(\ln(x-1) \cdot \frac{1}{\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}})} $$

And then they say that the given equation makes indeterminity $[\frac{\infty}{\infty}]$

First of all, it seems as if they take $\dfrac{1}{\ln(x-1)}$ as $\infty$ in numerator and then the $\dfrac{1}{\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}}$ as the $\infty$ in denominator. But $\ln(x-1)$ can't be zero as $x$ tends to one as ln is not defined for argument zero, no? And also then it takes cos function into numerator, how is it a equivalent conversion? Please explain!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{1}{(\cos \frac{\pi x}{2})\ln(x-1)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{(\cos \frac{\pi x}{2})}\ln(x-1)}
\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{\cos \frac{\pi x}{2}}{\ln(x-1)}
\end{align}$$

By L'Hopital's Rule we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{1}{(\cos \frac{\pi x}{2})\ln(x-1)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}}{\frac{1}{x-1}}
\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}-\dfrac{\pi }{2}(x-1)\sin \dfrac{\pi x}{2}
\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: But I don't understand how we can put a cos function in numerator, how is that a equivalent conversion?

Comment: you should consider only $x\to 1^+$

Comment: Using $\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{1}{(\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}} ) \cdot \ln(x-1)} = \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{\frac{1}{(\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}} )}}{ln(x-1)} $ and then applying L'Hopital's Rule two times should work...I get $+ \infty$ as solution, just like wolfram alpha, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E+1+(1%2F((cos(Pi*x%2F2))*ln(x-1))